# Svg Object moving along a line path and resizing with the window

Tags: javascript, svg, jquery-svg

I created a frame with an svg background (of a fantasy city). When I move over the buildings with the mouse they become red and if I click them I open a bubble with some information.
Now this city need people moving along the street.

Now the problem is that the people are moving along the svg path but if I resize the window the path isn't resizing but stay fixed.

I'm using var `SVGPath.getTotalLength();` to get the total length of the path, then inside a jQuery `$.each()` loop I get the coordinates of the point

```
var point = Path.getPointAtLength(v);
  var x = point.x;
  var y = point.y;
```

I don't understand where I'm wrong.

Here the CodePen with the code http://codepen.io/Angussimons/full/oZmNer/

Comment: In what coordinates do you need the position? In the SVG's? In your page's? You may need to convert from one to the other (check getCTM) and/or apply transform matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.
I'm posting here if someone else has the same problem.

The original size of the svg was 1920x1080.

So the solution to find the new X and Y adapted to the window size:

```
var x = (point.x * w) / 1920;
var y = (point.y * h) / 1080;
```

To get the window size I used jQuery `.width()` & `.height()` as follow:

```
var w = $(window).width();
var h = $(window).height();
```